# Partilha de ficheiros - php

Tags: phpmyadmin

Boa tarde, 
Tenho um site para fazer de partilha de informação, e a minha dúvida neste momento é como posso partilhar informação apenas para certos utilizadores que são escolhidos por mim?

Na base de dados tenho
User -cc,  nome, contacto, idInfo
Info - ID,  título, descrição

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria interessante criar uma tabela com permissões de acesso (utilizador_permissao) nela vincule o id do User com as paginas/pastas ou informações que voce quer que ele tenha acesso! Dessa forma o gerenciamento desse acesso fica mais simples! Espero ter ajudado! Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia. Na minha opinião devia ser criado uma tabela (`utilizador_escolhido`), com os campos (`codigo`, `codigo_utilizador`, `estado`).

A partir do momento momento que é escolhido um utilizador, insere-se o seu código na tabela utilizador_escolhido e no campo estado dessa mesma tabela é adicionado um valor.

Quando for partilhar informação, só são partilhadas as informações para os utilizadores cujo seu código encontra-se na tabela (`utilizador_escolhido`) e o estado desse mesmo utilizador nessa tabela é 1.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços.